# chnage tab text position after setvisibility

Tags: android, layout

I have a `tablayout` in android where i need to show a bullet like text sometimes and hide this bullet as needed. i design below layout for each tab item:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:gravity="bottom"
    >
<TextView

    android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/text_tab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <TextView
        android:text="•"
        android:textColor="@color/Notify"
        android:textSize="@dimen/badget_size"
        android:id="@+id/text_tab_counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

       />

</LinearLayout>
```

the problem is when i `setVisibility` of `text_tab_counter"` to `INVISIBLE` or `GONE`, `text_tab_counter"` move down . how can i design this layout to prevent this unexpected behavior?

Comment: It'd be better if you add images of what it looks like.

Comment: @Sufian , what's the difference ,i have problem with layout , not textview.

Comment: I said, add images of how the layout looks like before and after the changes. This will simplify the matter for answerers. Also, check if you have "instant run" checked if you're running Android Studio. It sometimes messes up the build.

Comment: @Sufian...sorry i misunderstood your answer ! i will upload the image now..

Comment: @Sufian i added picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of making visibility GONE try

```
    text_tab_counter.setText("");
```

also using weight with wrap_content is not a good practice. so you can remove weight while using wrap_content. If you want to use weight use android:layout_width="0dp" or android:layout_height="0dp" according to the LinearLayout orientation. android:layout_width="0dp" in your case.

also try setting gravity of LinearLayout to Bottom.

Comment: i changes my layout and edit my question ,but it didn't work out :(

Comment: try andriod:layout_gravity = "bottom" of text_tab

Comment: is this the complete xml? can you post the complete xml?

Comment: I just need to know how all texts are appearing at the bottom of the screen / layout. how come there is empty space above the text / badget. in my belief there is some parent ScrollView or HorizontalScrollView. that is why code looks incomplete to me.

Comment: Ir is inside an anctivity with toobar .theas space is toolbar .anyway it work out with your solution pluse ,i change `setvisibility` from `Gone` to `Invisibile` and it work out